# PostGIS, ST_Intersects & LIMIT performance question

Tags: postgis

I have a pretty standard table with one geometry column and a datetime column. Geom is indexed using gist and table is clustered + `VACUUM ANALYZE`. The Docker image is `kartoza/postgis:12.0`.

I consider the following query (bbox intersection):

```
SELECT product_id 
FROM products
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(
        geom, 
        ST_MakeEnvelope(%s, %s, %s, %s, 4326)
    )
LIMIT 1000
```

I have noticed the following behavior: query runs < 10ms when the bbox is below 1 deg² (returning 1000 rows), but the performance degrades as the AOI surface increases (for example, 250ms if the bbox is 20 deg x 20 deg).

I would have expected the opposite as PostGIS is more likely to find quickly 1000 products intersecting a bbox as the bbox is larger.

So I guess the LIMIT clause is not quite effective in my query.

How can I correct this behavior, and implement a robust & fast pagination?

Comment: You need to use `explain` on your queries to see what the optimiser is doing, at some point it may switch to sequential scans etc

Comment: Also, if that is a rectangular bbox, use `geom && ST_MakeEnvelope`

Comment: Indeed, explain analyze helped me solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: And what was the issue?