# PostGIS & Pagination

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a pretty standard table with a geom column and a gist index on it.
I would like to have a fast pagination on this table as it contains millions of rows.

The query involves a `ST_Intersects`:

```
SELECT id, geom 
FROM products
WHERE 
    ST_Intersects(
        geom, 
        ST_MakeEnvelope(%s, %s, %s, %s, 4326)
    )
```

However, there is no ordering with ST_Intersects, and the `OFFSET` clause adds a too large penalty.

Is there a way to achieve a fast and robust pagination with spatial geometries?

Comment: This is essentially the same question the poster made a few days ago.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/374461/postgis-st-intersects-limit-performance-question

Comment: My previous question was about a weird performance w.r.t. the area of a geometry that I solved using EXPLAIN ANALYZE. Here I am asking more generally about implementing constant time pagination with spatial indexes (like keyset pagination). I can rewrite the previous one if you think that's better.

Comment: what is wrong with the standard solution? (`select id ... where id > lastMaxID order by id limit 100`) You would have to run the spatial query for each page anyways.

Comment: It uses an index scan on the `id` but the spatial index does not kick in, hence the query is more than 10x slower.

Comment: see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131150/sorting-a-large-spatial-selection-is-not-using-gist-index-postgres-11-5/63133614#63133614). It contains ordering by `id+0` or to add an `offset 0` to prevent the default index from being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spatial index is of less concern here; you want to make sure you have an index on your `id` column!

Of course you can **order the return set of your query consistently by `id`** (or any other way), i.e.

```
SELECT id, geom
FROM   products
WHERE  geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(%s, %s, %s, %s, 4326)
ORDER BY
       id
;
```

and use `LIMIT/OFFSET` as you intended. Inconsistencies can only arise if that table gets rows inserted or updated at previous locations in your key column sequence during pagination requests.

---

**However:**

As you noted yourself, this can be a performance bottleneck. The issue here is that you have to **rerun the costly computation each time you request the next batch**, not so much the `LIMIT/OFFSET` penalty for large tables (for a simple `SELECT` on few million rows, you probably won't notice the increasing query time for increasing bounds *that* much, especially with clustered data and proper indexation). This rules out keyset pagination, too, as the concept here is to utilize the index by a filter clause; the main query still has to be run every time you request a batch.

If you can control the transaction flow, a cursor would be the way to go, e.g.

```
BEGIN;

DECLARE batch CURSOR FOR
  SELECT id, geom
  FROM   products
  WHERE  geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(%s, %s, %s, %s, 4326)
  ORDER BY
         id
;

FETCH 100
FROM  batch;         -- fetches first 100 entries and moves the cursor to the 101st position in the result set

MOVE RELATIVE + 100
FROM batch;          -- moves the cursor to the 201st position in the result set

FETCH 100
FROM  batch;         -- fetches 100 entries from position 201 to 300 and moves the cursor to the 301st position in the result set

CLOSE batch;

COMMIT;
```

This will return data from any position in consistent time over the result set.

But note that **a cursor only lives within a single transaction**; your client application needs `AUTO-COMMIT` turned off, and you will need to manage them yourself.

Comment: As for the issue that the spatial index doesn't kick in; as mentioned in comments above, the planner likely chooses a seq scan on the (smallish) result set, to avoid the index load; using a (`MATERIALIZED` for PG12 and above) *CTE* and then selecting from it via `LIMIT/OFFSET` as usual  can solve this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer geozelot! As I was afraid, a solution similar to keyset pagination cannot be implemented. I was hoping there was a hackish way to tell the spatial index where to resume its search and not to re-test for intersection. I did not know about MATERIALIZED, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ThomasCoquet Let me add: if you get a fraction only of a table with a few million rows, you can simply `CREATE OR REPLACE MATERIALIZED VIEW AS (<your_query_with_a_row_number_over_column>);` and add an index on it. You can refresh it whenever there is new data, and select from it using `LIMIT/OFFSET` with likely no noticeable overhead. You save the recomputation, and it is transaction agnostic.